# Problem with Event.ActivityDateTime field in Lightning compoenent

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to use the ActivityDateTime field of Event object in a lightning:formattedDateTime and it doesn't show anything. If I use a Date attribute of the component it works fine so I suppose the problem is with the field.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.events}" var="ev">
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!ev.ActivityDateTime}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: Sorry, the question is why it doesn't work, if that field is Date field, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo, There is no issue in "**lightning:formattedDateTime**" the behavior is working as expected.

Your `{!ev.ActivityDateTime}` would return Salesforce Date/DateTime Object like follows **2015-08-04T01:07:12.000Z.**

However this is not the format that **lightning:formattedDateTime** takes. The document clearly states

> This component uses the Intl.DateTimeFormat JavaScript object to format date values.

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedDateTime.htm

So you must do something as follows to get your formatted date.

**Component:**

```
<lightning:formattedDateTime aura:id="ltngDate" value="" />
```

**Controller :**

```
var d = new Date();
component.find("ltngDate").set("v.value",d);
```

This way we will be passing the Javascript Date Object not the Salesforce Object, The value also takes unix timestamp as arguments.

If we pass salesforce Date/DateTime Objects we will get the following error.

[image: Error]

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Anyway, finally I have used ui:outputDateTime that works fine with the salesforce object

Comment: Good choice, given that the above is still in beta =)